# php wait for function

Tags: php, function, wait

This is some example PHP code code;

```
<?php
function myFunc() {
    echo "blue";
}

for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    echo "I like the colour " . myFunc() . "</br>";
}
?>
```

This generates the output;

```
blueI like the colour 
blueI like the colour 
blueI like the colour 
blueI like the colour 
blueI like the colour
```

In my actual project, myFunc is making an MySQL call (if it makes any difference mentioning that). How can I make my loop wait for that function to return before carrying on otherwise the output is out of order like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `myFunc()` is evaluated before concatenating.  Return the value from `myFunc()` and use that in your loop, rather than echoing in `myFunc()`.

Comment: So why is the output out of order?

Comment: @javano: that's how PHP works. function calls in `echo` statements are executed before any output is done by the echo, so your echo inside the function executes/outputs BEFORE the parent echo call's output takes place

Comment: This makes complete sence now, *facepalm*. Thanks for that :D

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the the code to this:

```
<?php
function myFunc() {
    return "blue";
}

for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    echo "I like the colour " . myFunc() . "</br>";
}
?>
```

Take note the `return` rather than `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use `echo` in your function.  Use `return` instead.

When you evalute the loop, the function is evaluated first to see if there is a return value to put into the string.  Since you call `echo` and not `return`, the echo from the function is happening and then the echo from the loop is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use the return statement:

```
 <?php
 function myFunc() {
     return "blue";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
  function myFunc() {
      return "blue";
  }

  for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
      $color = myFunc();
      echo "I like the colour " . $color . "</br>";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not your problem, your problem is that you have two actions.

```
you are concatenating a string
you are calling a function.
```

The result string is the contcatenation between "I like the colour " . myFunc() . "", but before you can concatenate these values, you must execute myFunc().

When you execute myFunc, you are writing "blue" to the output.

then, the result are (for every line).

`blueI like the colour`
(first, evaluate myFunc() an then concatenate the return value (void) to the static string.

maybe you want to do that:

```
<?php    
function myFunc() {
        return "blue";
    }
for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    echo "I like the colour " . myFunc() . "</br>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Damn it, now that people have exmplaid this to me its seems blindingly obviousy. Thanks for clearing that up, totally makes sense :)